# Call css link from subcategory to main css folder

Tags: html, css

All my files are in a folder, called demo.mywebsite.com.
This folder is in the same location as the httpdocs folder.
The main css folder is located on this path.
httpdocs/all/css/(style.css etc).
How can I call a css file from this subcategory? I tried this but it does not work:

```
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "httpdocs/all/css/style.css" type = "text / css">
OR**strong text**
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../all/css/style.css" type = "text / css">
```

What should I write? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../httpdocs/all/css/style.css" type = "text / css">
```

Comment: I did it but still doesn't work.. Any other suggestion?.. Thanks

Comment: tell me exactly inside which folder you have you .html file ??

Comment: My .php file is inside the folder demo.mywebiste.com but my main css folder is located on this path. httpdocs/all/css/style.css

Comment: if this answer helps you in any way, please accept this answer. this would help me grow my profile. Thank You

Comment: I tried all these days, but for some reason it doesn't work. Of course if you help I will rate it as the best answer. In the folder httpdocs I have my main website(mywebsite.com). In the folder demo.mywebsite.com I have the register/login form. If I call a path from httpdocs  for example <a href="../../demo.mywebsite.com/index.php" it cant find url .. it gives this address https://www.mywebsite.com/demo.mywebsite.com/index.php  . The same with css path. I hope you understand ..

Comment: can you provide the link to the github ? i might can figure it out

Comment: No I cant do that.. It can't be so hard.. If you have any ideas please tell me.. thanks anyway

Comment: is httpdocs and demo.mywebsite.com is in the same directory ??

Comment: you should try this once: ../demo.mywebsite.com/form.html

Comment: Use direct hyperlinks ie  <a href="https://www.yourWebsite.com/">YourWebsite</a>